# Regex not working in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

So I'm trying to match up a regex and I'm fairly new at this. I used a validator and it works when I paste the code but not when it's placed in the codebehind of a .NET2.0 C# page.

The offending code is supposed to be able to split on a single semi-colon but not on a double semi-colon. However, when I used the string

"entry;entry2;entry3;entry4;"

I get a nonsense array that contains empty values, the last letter of the previous entry, and the semi-colons themselves. The online javascript validator splits it correctly. Please help!

My regex:

```
((;;|[^;])+)
```

Comment: Can you remove the javascript tag as this is a .NET question...

Comment: http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx is useful for checking regexes easily online, and so is http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/ on the desktop.  The second is also very useful for learning them.

Comment: I had used a javascript validator to validate my original regex. The difference between c# and javascript regex is apparently my problem, hence why I tagged it javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split on the following regular expression:

```
(?<!;);(?!;)
```

It means match semicolons that are neither preceded nor succeeded by another semicolon.

For example, this code

```
var input = "entry;entry2;entry3;entry4;";
foreach (var s in Regex.Split(input, @"(?<!;);(?!;)"))
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", s);
```

produces the following output:

```
[entry]
[entry2]
[entry3]
[entry4]
[]
```

The final empty field is a result of the semicolon on the end of the input.

If the semicolon is a *terminator* at the end of each field rather than a separator between consecutive fields, then use `Regex.Matches` instead

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, @"(.+?)(?<!;);(?!;)"))
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", m.Groups[1].Value);
```

to get

```
[entry]
[entry2]
[entry3]
[entry4]
```

Comment: Thanks! Too bad I was so far off with my original. This one leaves a trailing empty entry, any thoughts on how to get rid of that one?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `String.Split` on the semicolon?

```
string sInput = "Entry1;entry2;entry3;entry4";
string[] sEntries = sInput.Split(';');
// Do what you have to do with the entries in the array...
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: The "but not on double semicolons" requirement makes this *kind of* ugly.

Comment: the problem is that he doesn't want to split on double-semicolon (;;) hence String.Split() is inadequate for him.

Comment: Sorry Tom, this would not work because it would split on ALL semicolons and I need it to skip over double semi-colons, as stated in the original question.

Comment: @DrJokepu: If you look at his sample input, there is no double semicolon...and anyway if there was there would be an empty element in the offset in the array

Comment: You can tell split not to return empty values, use the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As tommieb75 wrote, you can use `String.Split` with `StringSplitOptions` Enumeration so you can control your output of newly created splitting array

```
string input = "entry1;;entry2;;;entry3;entry4;;";
char[] charSeparators = new char[] {';'};
// Split a string delimited by characters and return all non-empty elements.
result = input.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The result would contain only 4 elements like this:

> ```
> <entry1><entry2><entry3><entry4>
> ```

Comment: Please read the original question to see why this does not work. I knew only regex would work before I asked the question.

Comment: So you would like to split a;b;c;;d to [a][b][c;;d] or [a][b][c][d]. If it's the second, you can still use Split, but if it's the first I will delete my answer.